# Forming Multi-part request through RestKit

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, restkit, multipartform-data

This is my code to post multi-part data to server. What i observe is there is only image data being included in request, not the article object. Please let me know if someone has done this stuff successfully in the past. Thanks in advance.

```
 RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"title", @"author", @"body"]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping 
                                    objectClass:[Article class] rootKeyPath:@"article" method:RKRequestMethodAny];

[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

Article *article = [Article new];
article.title = @"Introduction to RestKit";
article.body = @"This is some text.";
article.author = @"Blake";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [objectManager multipartFormRequestWithObject:article
                                                                      method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                        path:path
                                                                  parameters:nil
                                                   constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

                                                       [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                                                                   name:imageInfo
                                                                               fileName:imageName
                                                                               mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

                                                   }];

RKObjectRequestOperation *operation1 = [objectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                               success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
{

    // Process data
    NSLog(@"success");

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    // An error occurred
    NSLog(@"error");

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this using appendPartWithHeaders. [Source](http://www.cnblogs.com/neozhu/archive/2013/01/19/2867569.html).
Lemme know if someone needs to see implementation more closely.